# Nhibernate query for Any condition

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have table structure like

```
Product {List<Cost> Costs}

Cost{List<Invoice> Invoices, Product product}

Invoice{bool isIncluded}
```

Need a query to get all Products which has any Cost for which none of invoice is included (isIncluded=false for all)

I tried something like:

```
Product pro= null;
Product p = null;

        var costQuery = QueryOver.Of<Cost>()
            .JoinAlias(c => c.Product, () => p)
            .Where(() => p.Id == pro.Id)                
            .WhereNot(c=>c.Invoices.Any(i=>i.IsIncluded))
            .Select(c => c.Id);

        var query = CurrentSession.QueryOver<Product>(() => pro)                
                                  .WithSubquery.WhereExists(costQuery);
```

Use of 'Any' in query errors out:

> Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean
>   Any[Invoice](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Trigger.StageGate.Services‌​.BusinessEntities.Invoice],
>   System.Func`2[Trigger.StageGate.Services.BusinessEntities.Invoice,System.Boolean‌​])

Comment: "Errors out"? Is this the exception message or compiler error you are getting? I don't think so. Please post the actual message.

Comment: exception msg
Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any[Invoice](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Trigger.StageGate.Services.BusinessEntities.Invoice], System.Func`2[Trigger.StageGate.Services.BusinessEntities.Invoice,System.Boolean])

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var costQuery = QueryOver.Of<Cost>()
        .JoinAlias(c => c.Product, () => p)
        .Where(() => p.Id == pro.Id)            
        .JoinQueryOver<Invoice>(c => c.Invoices)
        .WhereNot(i => i.IsIncluded)    
        .Select(c => c.Id);
```

Comment: Query would return all the costs which has any invoice with isIncluded false, while I am looking for costs which has none of the invoice with isIncluded true. Say if cost c1 has Invoices I1(isInclude= true), I2(=false), I3(=false). Cost c2 has Invoice I4(=false), I5(=false). Cost c3 has Invoice I6(=false). I need only cost c2 and c3, while query would return me all three c1 c2 c3.

Comment: updated the Query to 
Cost cost=null;
Cost cst=null;
  var invoiceQuery = QueryOver.Of<Invoice>()
            .JoinAlias(i=>i.Cost, () => cost)
            .Where(() => cost.Id == cst.Id)                
            .Where(i=>i.IsIncluded )
            .Select(c => c.Id);

  var costQuery = QueryOver.Of<Cost>(()=>cst)
            .JoinAlias(c => c.Product, () => p)
            .Where(() => p.Id == pro.Id)                
            .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(invoiceQuery)
            .Select(c => c.Id);

This works, but not sure if its the best way .

Comment: I don't think you can really do this without a subquery, and QueryOver doesn't support the enumerable extension methods (like Any, Contains, etc), you have to use QueryOver methods